# What is the proper Stack Exchange site to ask for legal advice on privacy policy?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

The question I asked on Stack Overflow, was about the `Google Maps API` privacy policy:

> (i) real time navigation or route guidance, including but not limited to turn-by-turn route guidance that is synchronized to the position of a user's sensor-enabled device.

Given my application introduces a certain behiavor/implementation, my question was whether the application still violates the privacy policy or not.

I fully understand this question is legal advice, and I deleted it soon after I asked it (2 people commented that it was indeed off topic). What is really bugging me is that similar questions have answers that seem to provide legal advice, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531391/is-it-possible-to-create-turn-by-turn-gps-navigation-app-on-android-using-google) (answer with most votes concludes: "It violates the policy").

So, is there a proper Stack Exchange site to ask for questions asking for legal advice? Optionally: Is it OK for Stack Overflow to have legal advice given as an answer, but not accepted as a question?

*Note: for users who can view deleted answers, my question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034250/is-using-text-to-speech-against-the-google-maps-api-privacy-terms-for-reading-di).*

Comment: Well can't see your question *(rep not high enough)* but the answer you link is from 2014 a lot has changed since then.

Comment: The privacy policy still aplies for Google Maps API, but at this point I'm not asking for advice on this, but where to ask about it. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Not what I'm saying, there are a lot of historical question / answers that you can argue don't fit with the site any more, all's I'm saying is the answer you linked is nearly two years old, attitudes could have changed. There is a list of what's on topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: http://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you both Lanykmart and Hans.

Comment: Seems like an off topic for law stackexchange as it is a specific matter unfortunately.

Comment: You might ask about it on [their Meta](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/). Include the proposed text of the question, and inquire about how to (re)-phrase it so that it would be on topic. But, I mean, really, for legal advice, you really need to consult a lawyer. Spending time and money developing an app without doing so first would really be irresponsible if this is at all a gray area.

Comment: For the optional part: I have been guilty of giving legal advice when a intended use case violated an unambiguously phrased TOS or law (i.e. "I want to store my users email address" when some TOS explictly stated "you must not store your users email address"). But if all I had to offer was legal advice I'd use a comment rather than an answer (both because IANAL, and because "it is not legal" does't answer the question if something is possible). But people may overlook restrictions within TOS, so I think there should be some wiggle room when it comes to pointing out potential legal hazards.

Comment: @DavidPostill ? "__un__ ambiguously phrased TOS"

Comment: There's a difference in their question-  they're asking if its possible (which I would close as too broad), but they're asking *how* to do it, not if its allowed.  Someone answered and said it's not.  Your question was explicitly asking if its allowed, that's off topic.  How to do it is on topic, even if it violates a TOS.

Comment: As for a legal advice SE site-  I think that's a horrible idea.  THe problem is that law is really specific to your exact circumstances, and permanent correct answers are difficult to give based on changing case law and interpretation.  I understand the desire, but it doesn't feel like a good match for SE.

Comment: I understand that my question was off topic. I knew it all along, the team leader insisted on asking and it is my fault entirely to failing on convincing them to not ask there. However, I find it a bit strange that a user does not answer the other question if technically is possible to create such an app, but they state that it is not, because of legal issues, and that answer complies with the SO answering guidelines.

Comment: Maybe my point of view is a bit blurred, but anyway. Thank you all and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Related: [How many questions on meta have asked, “Why can't I ask this question when that question is open”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124635/254466) I know that isn't what you asked here, but you did say it was bugging you. Don't let it bug you.